# How to get JS function option value form selector code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I code that shows a progress bar.

```
<div class="selector"></div>
```

The value that controls the bar's length is set by a Javascript function:

```
$(".selector").progressbar({
  value: 25
});
```

Now, I need a more flexible way to get the bar's length value from the selector code.

```
<div class="selector" length="25"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple `data-attribute` approach would fail, if you have more that one element with different lengths:

```
<div class="selector" data-length="25"></div>
<div class="selector" data-length="35"></div>
...
$('.selector').progressbar({
   length: $('.selector').data('length') /// produces 25
});
```

If you have control over a `progressbar` plugin - simply use `data-length` attribute, instead of the length, that is passed as an argument:

```
$.fn.progressbar = function(opts) {
   this.each(function(_, item) {
      var length = $(item).data('length');
      // do something with length
   });
};
```

In case you don't have control over it, create a wrapper plugin, like this:

```
$.fn.dataLengthProgressBar = function() {
   this.each(function(_, item) {
      $(item).progressbar({
         length: $(item).data('length')
      });
   });
};
```

```js
$.fn.progressbar = function() {
  this.each(function(_, item) {
    $item = $(item);
    $item.html($item.data('length') + ' is my length');
  });
};

$('.selector').progressbar();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector" data-length="25"></div>
<div class="selector" data-length="35"></div>
```

Comment: I used the first method but wrongly I get all to equal the first one data-length http://jsfiddle.net/hbLw34ec/ . Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Use a data attribute:

```
<div class="selector" data-length="25"></div>
```

You can extract this value using jQuery:

```
$(".selector").data("length"); //25
```

And modify it with similar syntax:

```
$(".selector").data("length", 30);
$(".selector").data("length"); //30
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to get the attribute value ? 
If yes then following will work:

`$( ".selector" ).attr('length');`

Comment: Though it will work, this isn't valid HTML - the use of data attributes is encouraged because the `length` attribute is an existing attribute and thus reserved by the HTML spec